flask session not found accross routes
run.py
from AdminUsers import createAdminUsersApp
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address
from flask_session import Session
import os
# Create Flask app for Admin Users
app = createAdminUsersApp()
limiter = Limiter(get_remote_address, app=app, storage_uri="memory://")
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'
Session(app)

# Apply CORS middleware to allow all origins, methods, and headers
# REMOVE STORAGE_URI = MEMORY WHEN DEPLOYING
CORS(app, origins="http://localhost:5173",supports_credentials=True, allow_headers=["*"])


# Set secret keys for both apps

from AdminUsers.SignIn import signinBP
limiter.limit("6 per hour")(signinBP)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Run both apps
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)


SignIn.py
from flask import request, jsonify, session, Blueprint
from pymongo import MongoClient
import bcrypt


signinBP = Blueprint('signin', __name__)
# Connect to MongoDB
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client['AutoLinks']
adminCredentialsCollection = db['AdminCredentials']
adminUsersCollection = db['Users']


@signinBP.route('/signin', methods=['POST'])
def signin():
    # Get email and password from request
    data = request.get_json()
    email = data.get('email')
    password = data.get('password')

    # Check if user with email exists
    userCredentials = adminCredentialsCollection.find_one({'email': email})
    if userCredentials:
        # Check if password matches
        if bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), userCredentials['password']):
            # this returns a string
            userID = userCredentials['_id']
            # Store user ID in sessions
            session['user_id'] = str(userID)
            session.modified = True
            # Find user in AdminUsersDB so that in the future
            # I can return the users name lastname address etc..
            userDetails = adminUsersCollection.find_one({'_id': str(userID)})
            if userDetails and userDetails['role'] == 'admin':
                # Password is correct, redirect to admin dashboard
                return jsonify({'message': "Login Successfull", 'status': 200})
            else:
                # User is not an admin, return error message
                return jsonify({'message': 'You do not have permission to access this resource!', 'status': 403})
        else:
            # Password is incorrect, return error message
            return jsonify({'message': 'Incorrect password!', 'status': 401})
    else:
        # User with email not found, return error message
        return jsonify({'message': 'User not found!', 'status': 404})


TireStock
from flask import jsonify, session, Blueprint
from pymongo import MongoClient

tireStockBP = Blueprint('tirestock', __name__)  # Update Blueprint name

# Connect to MongoDB
client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
db = client["AutoLinks"]
adminUsersCollection = db['Users']
tireStockCollection = db['TireStock']


def isAdmin(user_id):
    # Check if the user with the given user_id is an admin
    user_details = adminUsersCollection.find_one({'_id': user_id})
    return user_details and user_details['role'] == 'admin'


def getTireList():
    # Retrieve all tires from the TireStock collection
    tires = tireStockCollection.find({})
    # Convert MongoDB cursor to a list of dictionaries
    tireList = [{**tire, '_id': str(tire['_id'])} for tire in tires]
    return tireList


@tireStockBP.route('/tirestock', methods=['GET'])  # Update route
def tireStock():
    print(session.get('user_id'))
    if 'user_id' in session:
        print('its in session')
    if 'user_id' in session and isAdmin(session['user_id']):
        # Get all tire stock in tireStockCollection
        tireList = getTireList()
        return jsonify({'message': 'Welcome to the admin dashboard!', 'TireStock': tireList})
    else:
    #     # User is not authenticated or is not an admin, return a 403 Forbidden response
        return jsonify({'message': 'missing session'}), 403


_init.py
from flask import Flask
from .SignIn import signinBP
from .TireStock import tireStockBP
from .TireRegisters import tireRegisterBP
from .SignUp import signupBP
def createAdminUsersApp():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(signupBP)
    app.register_blueprint(signinBP)
    app.register_blueprint(tireStockBP)
    app.register_blueprint(tireRegisterBP)
    return app


Signin frontend axios call
const handleClick = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://127.0.0.1:5000/signin",
        { email: email, password: password },
        {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      );
      console.log(response.data);
      if (response.data.status === 200) {
        navigate("/tirestock");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(
        "Error has occured at signin_template from handleClick",
        error
      );
    }
  };

TireStock frontend
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/tirestock", {
          withCredentials: true,
        });
        // Assuming your server responds with data in JSON format
        setServerData(response.data.TireStock);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    };
    fetchData(); // Call the function when the component mounts
  }, []);

After a person sends their sign in email and password  it is then forwarded to the backend via POST with headers content type and with credentials true. In the backend im finding the email and password match in database adding userID into session then redirecting to /tirestock page(redirection happens on frontend after the 200 status confirmation). In the tirestock the frontend will try to GET data list from backend withCredentials:true. the tirestock backend will confirm ID in session before replying with the requested data. however the session recieved on tirestock backend is empty.
Keep in mind
im using blueprint my file structure is as follows
Flask:
run.py
Users:
init.py
signin.py
tirestock.py
The problem
when i set UserID inside session and check if its inside session from tirestock route its empty
